# c# Мониторинг изменения файла

Tags: c#, asp.net

Необходимо мониторить изменения файла `appsettings.json`. Вот код, который я использую для мониторинга.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
ConfigureMonitoring(builder.Services, builder.Configuration, serviceProvider);

private static void ConfigureMonitoring(IServiceCollection services, ConfigurationManager configuration, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    services.Configure<AppSettingsOptions>(configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

    var appSettings = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppSettingsOptions>>().Value;

    var fileProvider = configuration.GetFileProvider();
    var changeToken = fileProvider?.Watch("appsettings.json");
    changeToken?.RegisterChangeCallback(OnAppSettingsChanged, configuration);

    static void OnAppSettingsChanged(object state)
    {
        var configuration = (IConfiguration)state;
        var appSettings = configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettingsOptions>();
        var documentsPath = appSettings.DocumentsPath;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(documentsPath))
            Log.Warning($"{nameof(AppSettingsOptions.DocumentsPath)} cant be NullOrWhiteSpace");
        else
            Log.Information($"{nameof(AppSettingsOptions.DocumentsPath)} update");
    }
}
```

Код файла, который должен обновляться при обновлении файла `appsettings.json`

```
public class AppSettingsOptions
{
    public string DocumentsPath { get; set; }
}
```

Метод `OnAppSettingsChanged` не вызывается. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Что-то вы ооооочень перемудрили. Все уже придумано за вас, вам достаточно только включить нужные опции. Смотрите, вот вы регистрируете файл конфигурации, например так: `builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("settings.json");`, а теперь жмем запятую после пути к файлу, и смотрим, какие там параметры можно задать и видим там `string path, bool optional, bool reloadOnChange`, переписываем регистрацию на `builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("settings.json", false, true);`, ну и как-бы все, при изменении JSON файла, он будет автоматически десериализироваться, что обновит данные.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Мне важно не просто обновлять IConfiguration, а именно отслеживать каждое изменение файла конфигурации и проверять, всё ли с ним нормально при любом изменении. Я в ответах написал контроллер с той точки зрения, что потом можно будет улучшить этот код, добавив возможность не только на сервере локально файл изменять, но и через апи запросы

Comment: Начнем с того, что это также делается не так, как вы этого хотите. 1. Десериализация JSON в класс делается не через `.Get<AppSettingsOptions>()`, а через специальный механизм `IOptions<>`, вам надо лишь раз его зарегистрировать в сервисах (`builder.Services.Configure<SomeSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("SomeJsonSection"));` ) и дальше запрашивать его где угодно, как `IOptions<SomeSetting> settings`, где все значения будут в `settings.CurrentValue.SomeProperty`. 2. У опций есть разновидности, одна из которых `IOptionsMonitor`, которая и следит за тем, что было изменение.

Comment: Вам достаточно также попросить не `IOptions<>`, а уже `IOptionsMonitor<>`, использовать все значения также `settings.CurrentValue.SomeProperty`, а для отслеживания изменений достаточно подписаться на событие, например `settings.OnChange(Listener);`, где `Listener` это `void Listener(SomeSettings setting, string key){}`, который будет вызываться при изменении JSON файла конфигурации (если задан `reloadOnChange`  конечно.

Comment: Ну и 3. Мне кажется, вы не по назначению используете настройки, особенно если вы еще и изменяете их по запросу... Это медленно, это ненадежно, это странно... К тому-же, по умолчанию JSON настройки не поддерживают перезапись через код, они в режиме "ReadOnly", и чтоб это изменить, надо переписывать ридер полностью. Так что, советую задуматься, правильно-ли вы делаете сейчас...

Answer (score 0):

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class FileWatcherController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _appLifetime;

    public FileWatcherController(IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        _appLifetime = appLifetime;
        InitializeFileWatcher();
    }

    //тут потом добавлю логику по изменению файла конфигурации сервера

    private void InitializeFileWatcher()
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "appsettings.json");

        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = CreateFileSystemWatcher(filePath))
        {
            _appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true);
        }
    }

    private FileSystemWatcher CreateFileSystemWatcher(string filePath)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath), Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Changed += OnFileChanged;

        return watcher;
    }

    private void OnFileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsFileValid(e.FullPath))
            Log.Warning("Файл некорректен.");
    }

    private bool IsFileValid(string filePath)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```